# How to deduce from these inequalities that $x_n\to 0$ in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, sobolev-spaces

Let $p, h, d\in\mathbb{R}, h>0, p>1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\ge 2$. Let $(x_n)_n\subset (W_0^{1, p}(\Omega),\|\cdot\|)$. During the class of today, the lecturer said that the inequalities
$$\|x_n\|^p\left(h^{\frac{n}{n-p}}-\|x_n\|^{\frac{p^2}{n-p}}\right)\le o(1)$$
and
$$\|x_n\|^p\le n(d +c_1)+o(1)$$
for a real positive constant $c_1$, ensure that $x_n\to 0$ in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$ provided that
$$d<\frac{h^{\frac{n}{p}}}{n}-c_1.$$
Actually, I don't understand why. Could someone please help me to justify that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$d+\epsilon=\frac{h^\frac{n}{p}}{n}-c_1$$  By construction, $\epsilon>0$.

Substituting into your second bound, we have $$\|x_n\|^p\leq n(d+c_1)+o(1)=h^{\frac{n}{p}}-\epsilon n+o(1)$$  Raising to $\frac{p}{n-p}$<sup>th</sup> power, \begin{align*}
\|x_n\|^{\frac{p^2}{n-p}}&\leq(h^{\frac{n}{p}}-\epsilon n+o(1))^{\frac{p}{n-p}} \\
&=h^{\frac{n}{n-p}}\left(1-\frac{p}{n-p}\cdot\epsilon n+o(1)\right) \\
&=h^{\frac{n}{n-p}}\left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{n}}\cdot(1+o(1))\right)
\end{align*}  Thus $$h^{\frac{n}{n-p}}-\|x_n\|^{\frac{p^2}{n-p}}\geq h^{\frac{n}{n-p}}\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{n}}\cdot(1+o(1))=\Omega(1)$$ (using [Knuth's "Big Omega"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation)).

Finally, rearranging your first bound then gives $$\|x\|^p\leq\frac{o(1)}{\Omega(1)}$$ as required.